# about the differentiation of $n^{1.2}\log\log\log n$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Could anyone help to resolve this question?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} {n\log n \over n^{1.2}\log\log\log n}$$

So in this question  I try to use the L'Hopital's rule and do the differentiation, I could not get rid of the 'logloglogn' during the differentiation process, and this equation seems to be becoming more and more complicated.

for example:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} {n\log n \over n^{1.2}\log\log\log n}$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} {(n \log n)' \over (n^{1.2}\log\log\log n)'}$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} {1/n \over 0.2n^{-0.8}\log\log\log n+n^{0.2}(\log\log n)^{-1}(\log n)^{-1}(n)^{-1}}$$

So is there any good way to deal with this question and get the result?

Comment: I have edited my original question and add more details about where I am confused.

Comment: Please use proper formatting. As you can see, if cause serious issues if you don't. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Just a note: By editing the question after it was put on hold (excellent edit, by the way) it was pushed in the reopen review queue. When the edit fixes the problems that caused the question to be put on hold, the question is typically reopened by the reviewing. Depending on how many reviewers are active at the time, that can take a couple of hours (or be done in a few minutes). You should wait a little longer before flagging to give the queue time to do its work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you didn't do any errors (I haven't checked). You can simplify your last equation:
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty} {1/n \over 0.2n^{-0.8}\log\log\log n+n^{0.2}(\log\log n)^{-1}(\log n)^{-1}(n)^{-1}}\\
=&\lim_{n \to \infty} {1 \over \underbrace{0.2n^{0.2}\log\log\log n}_{\to \infty}+ \underbrace{n^{0.2}(\log\log n)^{-1}(\log n)^{-1}}_{\to \text{not negative number or }\infty}} = 1 / \infty = 0
\end{align}